# Open the start menu in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating an application which simulates the charms bar in Windows 8 (don't ask why) however when I click on "start" I need it to show the windows start menu.

Do you know what code could be used to open the start menu?
I have been searching for quite a while however I can't find anything!

I'm using vb.net, thanks in advance.

Comment: If the answer(s) help and/or work, do the Right Thing and upvote them.

Comment: I have done that!